# How to change the index of a series into joined label names of indices?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series that looks like this

```
ser:
         profit
2003-01    5
2003-02    5
2003-03    5
```

And I want to take the cumulative sum of ser which is executed by the code
`profit.cumsum()`. I want now the index of `ser` to look like this. Unfortunately, there is no option that will make it look like this in using `cumsum()`

```
ser:
                    profit
2003-01               5
2003-01 to 2003-02    10
2003-01 to 2003-03    15
```

Thank you very much to those who will answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension with `f-string`s and if-else for processing:

```
df.index = [x if i == 0 else f'{df.index[0]} to {x}' for i, x in enumerate(df.index)]
print (df)
                    profit
2003-01                  5
2003-01 to 2003-02       5
2003-01 to 2003-03       5
```

Or:

```
df.index = np.hstack((df.index[0], df.index[0] + ' to ' + df.index[1:]))
print (df)
                    profit
2003-01                  5
2003-01 to 2003-02       5
2003-01 to 2003-03       5
```